# Visual Studio 2010 No permite crear proyecto

Tags: c#, visual-studio

necesito su ayuda porfavor, tengo Visual Stidio 2010 Professional en español y me aparece el error de la imagen, tengo windows 7 enterprise 64bits

Ya intente des instalar e instalar desde 0, reparar, también resetear las configuraciones, reinstalar framework 4, y por si acaso instalar framework 4.5, tambien probe con devenv.exe /installvstemplates

Lo otro importante es que si puedo abrir proyectos antiguos, pero no me permite compilar ni ejecutarlos

En la maquina tengo visual studio 2008, sql server management studio 2012, los cuales funcionan sin problemas

Favor si alguien tiene una idea de como corregir este problema, estare muy agradecido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: no hay un log de errores por algun lado? si hiciste todo eso, deberia estar logueado en algun lado.

Comment: imagino que si, pero desconozco donde quedan los logs de instalacion

Comment: Hermano ese visual es que viene instalado en el sql server fíjate bien el visual

Comment: Parece que ha habido un problema en la instalación del VS y no se han instalado los templates. Probablemente una desinstalación seguida de un instalación solucione el problema.